# Ant not recognizing classpath

Tags: java, ant, classpath, javac

I can't see why this Ant task fails:

```
<javac srcdir="src" destdir="bin" verbose="true" classpath="lib/*;${MyCommons.proj.path}/MyCommons.jar" />
```

My jars are all in lib, plus one external jar. When I mouse-over the classpath section eclipse shows all the jar files are recognized by this configuration.

On compile, I get 100 errors of can't find this package or symbol (it's not finding the jars).

```
[javac] Compiling 51 source files to C:\MyProjects\MyCommons\bin
[javac] C:\MyProjects\MyCommons\src\com\proxyandvpn\datamodel\Notification.java:3: package org.joda.time does not exist
[javac] import org.joda.time.DateTime;
[javac]                     ^
[javac] C:\MyProjects\MyCommons\src\com\proxyandvpn\datamodel\Transaction.java:5: package org.joda.time does not exist
[javac] import org.joda.time.DateTime;
```

I've tried every format of classpath I can find, classpathref's, embedded , filesets, filelists, , etc. for about an hour.

Does anyone see an error?

---

Prior to this call I have a call to

```
<ant target="compile" dir="/some/other/project"/>
```

Removing this allowed the javac command to compile successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should try this (did not run myself but I think it works):

```
<path id="some.classpath">
    <fileset dir="lib">
        <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <pathelement location="${MyCommons.proj.path}/MyCommons.jar"/>
</path>
```

and then

```
<javac srcdir="src" destdir="bin" verbose="true">
    <classpath refid="some.classpath"/>
</javac>
```

If there are errors, put them in comments. I will correct it.

Comment: Aha, wait, I just removed a previous call to <ant ...> which compiles the MyCommons.jar that I need and it compiles when I do that. The other build file must be mingling with this one in some odd way that I'm not yet familiar with.

Comment: You can add debug printing of classpath: 

    <property name="myclasspath" refid="some.classpath"/>
    <echo message="Classpath = ${myclasspath}"/>

Maybe the problem is in base directory. Are you sure that relative links are correct?

Comment: My mistake, the error was not with this task, but with the compile task of the dependent project. I kept trying to change the classpath of this project, when I should have been making those fixes to the other, dependent project. Thanks for helping me at least know that I was doing this right so I could focus my attention away from the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. This helped me:

```
<ant target="compile" dir="/some/other/project" inheritAll="false"/>
```